# Call part of the URL

Tags: javascript, html

below code is working for me

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" border="2" onClick="test();" >
<script>
function test() {alert(window.location.href);}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result is "file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.html" is there any way to retrieve result as "file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/"

Thanks,

Comment: This is a basic substring operation.

Comment: "Call part"? It's known as the *base path*. If you search for that term, you surely will find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With simple string manipulation methods of **[`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** and **[`.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)**:

```js
var theLocation = "file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.html";
// Get a substring of the original that starts at the beginning of the string
// and ends where the last / is, plus one (to include the / at the end).
var theNewLocation = theLocation.substr(0, theLocation.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
console.log(theNewLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a substring basic operation.

Steps are :

1. Get your URL with line you have done
2. Look for the index of the last occurence of /
3. Substring the string from 0 to the index find before

   ```js
       var locationStart = window.location.href;
       //for test exemple
   locationStart ="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.html";
       var refactoreLocation = locationStart.substr(0, locationStart.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
       console.log(refactoreLocation);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `window.location.hostname` instead of `window.location.href`. `hostname` gives the name of the `server/root folder name`, the file is running on.

Or

If you want to get the path to the folder name as yous said, **file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/** you can use the following snippet

```js
var getUrl = window.location;
    function test() {  
    var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + base(getUrl.pathname);
    alert(baseUrl);
    }

    function base(b){
        var parts = b.split('/');
        var i;
        var url = '';
        for(var i=1; i< parts.length-1; i++) {
            url = url + parts[i]+"/";
        }
        return url;
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Here" border="2" onClick="test();" >
```